# HTTP ERROR 404 in Accessing Jenkins Build Pipeline Console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After configuring Jenkins , getting error when i click on console image 
in  Build Pipeline.

The problem is because of /view/jobName  repeated twice in URL.

How can i resolve this

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing           

/view/<jobName>/view/<jobName>/job/<jobName>/2571/console
. Reason:
Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: Do we have any progress for this issue?